# Converting single column, single row XML data to SQL table

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, t-sql

I have a table called XMLTest, with a single column called Val with XML datatype

```
create table XMLTest(Val XML)
```

Into this table I read this data:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
  <SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <ns0:getInterestAndExchangeRatesResponse xmlns:ns0="http://swea.riksbank.se/xsd">
      <return xmlns="">
        <datefrom xmlns="">2020-03-25</datefrom>
        <dateto xmlns="">2020-03-26</dateto>
        <groups xmlns="">
          <groupid xmlns="">130</groupid>
          <groupname xmlns="">Currencies against Swedish kronor</groupname>
          <series xmlns="">
            <seriesid xmlns="">SEKEURPMI</seriesid>
            <seriesname xmlns="">1 EUR</seriesname>
            <unit xmlns="">1.0E0</unit>
            <resultrows xmlns="">
              <date xmlns="">2020-03-25</date>
              <period xmlns:ns1="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="" ns1:nil="true" />
              <min xmlns:ns1="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="" ns1:nil="true" />
              <average xmlns:ns1="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="" ns1:nil="true" />
              <max xmlns:ns1="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="" ns1:nil="true" />
              <ultimo xmlns:ns1="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="" ns1:nil="true" />
              <value xmlns="">1.08823E1</value>
            </resultrows>
          </series>
        </groups>
      </return>
    </ns0:getInterestAndExchangeRatesResponse>
  </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

So the final result is all of this data in a single column & single row. I've tried to extract the relevant data from this XML. I'm interested in seriesid & its value. So the final output would be:

```
seriesid | value
SEKEURPMI| 1.08823E1
```

and ultimately there will be multiple  so the results would be more like:

```
seriesid | value
SEKEURPMI| 1.08823E1
SEKUSDPMI| 1.3823E1
....     | ...
```

However I'm having problems creating valid query to get this information. None of the solutions I've been trying work with mine because I'm querying directly from a table. I've been trying to implement this solution: [How can I save data from xml to sql 2008?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21156732/how-can-i-save-data-from-xml-to-sql-2008) but I don't seem to be able to apply the same technique when querying from a table.

Comment: Check if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37658615/tsql-how-to-split-xml-and-insert-them-as-rows/37658757#37658757

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it like this:

```sql
DECLARE @yourTable TABLE(ID INT IDENTITY,Val XML);
INSERT INTO @yourTable VALUES
(N'<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
  <SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <ns0:getInterestAndExchangeRatesResponse xmlns:ns0="http://swea.riksbank.se/xsd">
      <return xmlns="">
        <datefrom xmlns="">2020-03-25</datefrom>
        <dateto xmlns="">2020-03-26</dateto>
        <groups xmlns="">
          <groupid xmlns="">130</groupid>
          <groupname xmlns="">Currencies against Swedish kronor</groupname>
          <series xmlns="">
            <seriesid xmlns="">SEKEURPMI</seriesid>
            <seriesname xmlns="">1 EUR</seriesname>
            <unit xmlns="">1.0E0</unit>
            <resultrows xmlns="">
              <date xmlns="">2020-03-25</date>
              <period xmlns:ns1="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="" ns1:nil="true" />
              <min xmlns:ns1="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="" ns1:nil="true" />
              <average xmlns:ns1="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="" ns1:nil="true" />
              <max xmlns:ns1="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="" ns1:nil="true" />
              <ultimo xmlns:ns1="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="" ns1:nil="true" />
              <value xmlns="">1.08823E1</value>
            </resultrows>
          </series>
        </groups>
      </return>
    </ns0:getInterestAndExchangeRatesResponse>
  </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>');
```

--the query

```sql
SELECT t.ID
      ,A.gr.value('(groupid/text())[1]','int') AS groupId
      ,A.gr.value('(groupname/text())[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS groupName
      ,B.sr.value('(seriesid/text())[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS seriesId
      ,B.sr.value('(seriesname/text())[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS seriesName
      ,C.rw.value('(date/text())[1]','date') AS rowDate
      ,C.rw.value('(period/text())[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS rowPeriod
      ,C.rw.value('(value/text())[1]','float') AS rowValue
FROM @yourTable t
CROSS APPLY t.Val.nodes('//groups') A(gr)
OUTER APPLY A.gr.nodes('series') B(sr)
OUTER APPLY B.sr.nodes('resultrows') C(rw);
```

The idea in short and some background:

- The plural form of `<groups>`, `<series>` and `<resultrows>` lets me think, that this is nested, `1:n` related data, hence the *cascade* of `APPLY ...nods()`.
- This XML has a mess of wrong namespaces...
- It would be awfully ugly to define/declare all namespaces properly...
- Gladfully alle the values are living in an empty default namespace.
- To avoid the namespaces I start with `//groups`. The double `//` triggers a deep search. **Don't follow this suggestion, if an element `<groups>` might occure anywhere else!**
- We get all groups
- We get all series within each group
- We get all rows within each serie

Hint: about the `ns1:nil="true"`. Assumingly this was generated with T-SQL using `ELEMENTS XSINIL`. XML would omit NULL values by default. That means, that the reader should know the schema. Asking for a missing element will then return NULL. but in this case all elements are generated. We can test if the `nil` attribute is `true`. But in this case it is easier to test for the `text()` node. This is missing and will implicitly return NULL.

Some remarks about namespaces:

- The namespaces to name the `SOAP` related parts are okay, the namespace to specify the element `<getInterestAndExchangeRatesResponse>` is okay too.
- But the often used `xmlns=""` is really odd. This will define an empty default namespace again and again...
- I assume that this is generated with T-SQL using nested `FOR XML` calls and by stuffing such a pre-generated content XML into the SOAP envelope.

Comment: Thank you, wasn't expecting a full solution but you provided one. even with great comments on how to extend it, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're after? The declaration of the namespaces is really important here:

```
DECLARE @XML xml = '<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
  <SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <ns0:getInterestAndExchangeRatesResponse xmlns:ns0="http://swea.riksbank.se/xsd">
      <return xmlns="">
        <datefrom xmlns="">2020-03-25</datefrom>
        <dateto xmlns="">2020-03-26</dateto>
        <groups xmlns="">
          <groupid xmlns="">130</groupid>
          <groupname xmlns="">Currencies against Swedish kronor</groupname>
          <series xmlns="">
            <seriesid xmlns="">SEKEURPMI</seriesid>
            <seriesname xmlns="">1 EUR</seriesname>
            <unit xmlns="">1.0E0</unit>
            <resultrows xmlns="">
              <date xmlns="">2020-03-25</date>
              <period xmlns:ns1="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="" ns1:nil="true" />
              <min xmlns:ns1="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="" ns1:nil="true" />
              <average xmlns:ns1="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="" ns1:nil="true" />
              <max xmlns:ns1="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="" ns1:nil="true" />
              <ultimo xmlns:ns1="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="" ns1:nil="true" />
              <value xmlns="">1.08823E1</value>
            </resultrows>
          </series>
        </groups>
      </return>
    </ns0:getInterestAndExchangeRatesResponse>
  </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>';

WITH XMLNAMESPACES ('http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope' AS [SOAP-ENV],'http://swea.riksbank.se/xsd' AS ns0, 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' AS ns1)
SELECT V.X.value('(SOAP-ENV:Envelope/SOAP-ENV:Body/ns0:getInterestAndExchangeRatesResponse/return/groups/series/seriesid/text())[1]','varchar(10)') AS seriesid,
       V.X.value('(SOAP-ENV:Envelope/SOAP-ENV:Body/ns0:getInterestAndExchangeRatesResponse/return/groups/series/resultrows/value/text())[1]','float') AS [value]
FROM (VALUES(@XML))V(X)
```